# ActiveAdmin: use menu label and menu parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm trying to set custom menu labels for menu parent in `active_admin` like

```
Parent label
  custom label 1
  custom label 2
  custom label 3
```

The problem is when I set it like

```
ActiveAdmin.register Example do

  menu parent: 'Parent'
  menu label: 'Label 1'

end
```

menu parent doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
menu parent: 'Parent', label: 'Label 1'
```

Comment: is there a way to specify which custom label should go first or second?

Comment: You can set priority: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#customize-the-menu